# How do I reference a Javascript file from a GSP file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I have a Javascript file located at `assets/javascripts/js/line.js`.

I am trying reference the file from one of my GSP files, but I am not able.

In the GSP file I have this tag: `<asset:javascript src="/js/line.js" />`

The file at this path is not being fetched when the GSP file is rendered.

What is the correct way to reference this Javascript file from the GSP file?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
<asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></asset:javascript>
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$("#tabs").css("display","block");
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Tab 1 Content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Tab - 2 Content</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Tab - 3 Content</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, there will be very little anyone can do to help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to explain the issue a little more clearly. Hopefully this format will help you see how best to ask questions that will help us answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to add specific js

```
<script src="../assets/js/line.js"></script>
```

The better way is to add

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

in the \layouts\main.gsp file. Then add

```
//= require jquery-1.4.2.min
```

in application.js file.

Note: Make sure application.js and jquery-1.4.2.min.js are stored in the assets\javascripts folder

Comment: I am sorry its not working. I am trying to implement the jquery-1.4.2.min.js in the gsp. But not able to get the js working.But the same concept works in the grails 1.3.7 and not in grails 3.2.8

Comment: <asset:javascript src="application.js"/> works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly place your javacsript files to this directory

```
your_project\grails-app\assets\javascripts\
```

Then add this line to your GSP

```
<asset:javascript src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
```

As you are using `Grails 3.2.8` then you should use [jquery-2.2.0.min.js](http://minime.stephan-brumme.com/files/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js) then it will work as well

Comment: thansk a lot for your reply .... Attached my code in my question ... Its still not working....